# Grails app index page URL

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to shorten the URL to get to my grails app. Currently the shortest I can get it to is

```
http://myserver:8080/helloWorld/helloWorld/
```

HelloWorld is the controller name and the app name. Can I make it shorter somehow so its only

```
http://myserver:8080/helloWorld/
```

I have URL mappings set to

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `HelloWorldController` the default URL by changing

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

to

```
"/"(controller: 'helloWorld')
```

This uses the default action in that controller (likely `index()`); if you want a different action, do this:

```
"/"(controller: 'helloWorld', action: 'theOtherName')
```

Comment: can I change the name of the URL from helloWorld to something else without changing the controller name

Comment: Yes, as @ataylor mentioned in his answer you can change the context using `grails.app.context`; in his example it's blank but you can change it to whatever, e.g. `grails.app.context = "/foo"`

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one controller, there's no need to have it in the URL.   You could use the following mapping:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$action?/$id?"(controller:'helloWorld')
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

In this case, `http://myserver:8080/helloWorld/` will go to `HelloWorldController.index()` instead of serving up the `index.gsp` view.

The leading `helloWorld` is also optional.  Add these lines to your `Config.groovy` to use the root context:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
grails.serverURL = "http://myserver:8080"
```

Combining both of these will allow you app be accessed through `http://myserver:8080/`.

Comment: In grails 2.5.4, I only needed one of the 2 properties set to be able use use the root of the url as my index: grails.app.context = "/"